# Why is this theorem important in fulton's book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory

In Fulton algebraic curves book, we have the following proprieties which help us to find the intersection number of  a pair of function at a given point.

[image]
[image]

afterwards he states this theorem:

[image]

What's the advantage of this characterization? I think it's simpler to use the proprieties of the intersection numbers to find them instead use this theorem.

Anyone have a simple example how this theorem can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to know there _is_ a well-defined intersection number even if all you are going to do later is use the axioms...

Comment: @ZhenLin Is this the only function of this theorem?

Comment: @user42912 You say this as if it's unimportant! You can't do anything with intersection numbers if you haven't proved that "intersection numbers" actually exist...